# Android NavController UI test not changing screen on performClick

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, ui-testing

I am trying to do a simple test where:

> Screen 1 -> Click Next Button -> Screen 2

Currently if I launch the app the normal way and click on the button the next screen is displayed.

Clicking the button executes:

```
navController.navigate(NEXT_SCREEN)
```

When I try to do the same thing in a test and perform the button click:

```
  composeTestRule.onNodeWithContentDescription(composeTestRule.activity.getString(R.string.continue_button))
        .assertIsDisplayed()
        .performClick()
```

It just completes the test successfully and closes without showing the next screen. I tried adding  **composeTestRule.waitForIdle()** after the **performClick** but it still behaves the same way it just completes the test without showing the next screen. Not sure what I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check that the next screen was shown, just add some assertion of that screen.
Let's assume the next screen has the text "I'm the next one", you can add next code into your test:

```
composeTestRule.onNode(hasText("I'm the next one")).assertIsDisplayed()
```

This line checks that the second screen was opened.